# Word 2007: Arabic/Persian number in picure caption

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I am working on a Word document that contains both Arabic/Persian and English words and numbers.

Problem is if I add a caption for an image, its sequential number is in Latin format(123456789) not Arabic format(١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩). like this: 
شکل 2
That must be:
شکل ٢

Change `Numeral` settings in Word Options > Advanced > Show document content
to `Hindi` will solve this problem but makes all numbers in Arabic format, that is not desired. Other `Numeral` options is tested but did not solve this issue (`Context` option makes numbers in Arabic format but didn't work for caption numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Using `Context` works correctly for caption numbers in word 2016 and 2013.
In Word 2016 I have

تصویر ۱

using `Context`.
You may need to upgrade your Microsoft Office Word.